# Greek letters in fancyvrb verbatim on OS X using xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, mac, fancyvrb

How can I get greek letters, such as λ, to appear inside Verbatim? Which font should I use?

I am on OS X, using xelatex, and currently using

```
\fvset{fontfamily=Monaco(0),fontsize=\footnotesize,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

When I try it, the logs show:

```
Missing character: There is no λ in font Monaco/AAT!
```

Which kind of makes sense, as trying it in the font book also does not show λ when using Monaco, or Courier. But the browser has no problem rendering λ when the font is set to Monaco.

Answer (score 2):

The default monospace font on OS X is now actually Menlo, which does include the character. So the solution was to use it:

```
\newfontfamily{\menlofont}{Menlo}
```

To define the font and:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=Menlo(0)]
  Happy λ
\end{Verbatim}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is that 0 for?

Comment: You're better doing `\setmonofont{Menlo}` and your life will be easier.

Comment: In Linux, \setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono} works. It's also included in the `fonts-extra`package.